# Methods that change a value, and not return anything

Tags: java, arrays

Please what's the term for methods that alter the contents of a variable, while not returning anything.

For instance in Java from the `java.util.Arrays` class the static method `sort` sorts an array internally and sets the sorted array to the *original arrays variable* (not sure).

```
import static java.util.Arrays.sort;
public class bs {
public static void main(String [] args){

    int[] arr = {3,2,4,8,2,5,33,12,19,15,20};
    sort(arr); // doing this stuff <<<< and not int [] arr1 = sort(arr); 
  }
 }
```

**1** - Is there a specific term for that kind of method,

and;

**2** - How does this work internally? Does it delete the original variable and assign the sorted values to a fresh one with that same name or??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd normally call it a *mutator* - or just talk about it having side-effects. (Usually a mutator is a method you call *on* an object which changes that object's state. In this case we're changing the object referred to by the argument/parameter, which is *slightly* different.)

As for how it works - it's important to understand the difference between a *variable*, a *reference* and an *object*.

This method call:

```
sort(arr);
```

copies the value of the `arr` variable as the value of the parameter within the `sort` method. That value is a *reference* to an object (the array in this case). The method doesn't change the value of `arr` at all - it's still a reference to the same array. However, the method changes the *contents* of the array (i.e. which elements have which values).

Answer (score 3):

There is a name for that: an anti-pattern ;)

Seriously, I consider overusing them a bad practice: as much as possible, methods should not modify the world outside of them, it's far better (and far more Object-oriented) to put the result in a temp array that you return at the end of your processing. If you don't want to do that, and use methods which mutate other elements, you *will* run into all kind of problems (breaking of encapsulation, concurrency problems, etc.) that you could avoid much more easily without doing that.

Exception: setters, of course.

As for how it works, Jon Skeet said it in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Methods which return a value are sometimes called "functions" and those which don't return anything "procedures".

Answer (score 0):

Methods and the methods header (`Public static void main string` or something like that) is the method header.  Main method is the usual starting point for all stand alone java applications. The word "static" is a method modifier. "Void" means that this method does not return a value when it is called.