# Java method returning object or directly manipulate it?

Tags: java, methods, return

I have come upon this (to me weird) piece of code. I have actually never seen this used and never used it myself, so it was something quite confusing... which goes along the lines of

- using hashmap as an example here, but other objects would behave the same

```java
public static void fillData(HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap){
    dataMap.put("key","value");
}
```

Now this was very confusing, as the way I learned you do it is more like this

```java
public static HashMap<Object, Object> fillData(){
    HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataMap.put("key","value");
    return dataMap;
}
```

Now is there a time when I should use one way or the other? Im still pretty new to programming, but I havent found much of anything about this type of structure.

I also have experimented around and found this only works with objects, and not primitives...

Comment: In general you should try to avoid modifying arguments, but there are situations where this is not possible.

Comment: This question and the answers might be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931523/methods-that-change-a-value-and-not-return-anything

Comment: BTW: primitives are passed by value and therefore you are manipulation a copy only in the method which has no effect on the caller side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, think about the case where the method manipulates an existing non-empty map. In that case the first example makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

I was googling this same subject in the morning and came across  [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245767/is-it-an-antipattern-modifying-an-incoming-parameter), which states that the first form of

```
public static void fillData(HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap){
    dataMap.put("key","value");
}
```

is considered "a bad practice, vestigial or pre-OOP times."

Answer (score 2):

The practice I follow is based on two scenarios:

Scenario 1. If the calling method make changes to a complex object that is passed to the method then it makes more sense to modify the passed object and return nothing (void) from the method. The objects are passed-by-value in java (the "value" here refers to object reference information that is copied and passed) so any modification will update master copy of the object and nothing is required to be returned from the method.

Scenario 2. If the calling method utilize passed complex object, run some logic and prepare another type of complex object then it makes sense to create and return this new object from the method.

Coming back to your question - 
Its a static method so its instance independent. I can think of two possible scenarios again:

Scenario 1- If your "dataMap" could be initiated before this method call and it could have some other key-value pair already then it is more simpler to pass this "dataMap" and let the method update this same map with appended key-value pair. Nothing will be returned back in this case.

Scenario 2- If your "dataMap" is always supposed to be a fresh empty map before this method call then I do not see any reason to create Map instance and pass this in the method. It will be less lines of code and simpler if the method creates this map and return in as method return parameter.

Both ways have their applicability as per a given scenario and I would not say one is better over other.

Answer (score 1):

On java, a method parameter which is not primitive holding reference to object. 
On your example

```
public static void fillData(HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap){
    dataMap.put("key","value");
}
```

dataMap referencing an object and any changes on this object effects whole system references which are showing this object.

for example;

```
public static void fillAll(){
        HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap2 = dataMap;
        HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap3 = dataMap;
        //dataMap1, dataMap2, dataMap3 are same object's references.
        fillData1(dataMap1);
        fillData2(dataMap2);
        fillData3(dataMap3);
        //here dataMap1 holds 3 different values in it.
        //dataMap2, dataMap3 still same as dataMap1 
        dataMap3 = new HashMap<>();
        //here dataMap3 have a new object's reference but dataMap1 and dataMap2 still have 3 values in the map object.
        //primitive types are different they are holding values directly.
        int x = 5;
        int y = x;
        x++; //now x value is 6 but y value is still 5
}

public static void fillData1(HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap){
    dataMap.put("key1","value1");
}

public static void fillData2(HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap){
    dataMap.put("key2","value2");
}

public static void fillData3(HashMap<Object, Object> dataMap){
    dataMap.put("key3","value3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a look on the usage of such APIs (replaced `HashMap` by `Map`, to use an interface instead of a concrete implementation is always better):

```
Map<Object, Object> data = new Map<>();
fillData(data);
```

Such pass through parameter create side effect code which is not visible from the API.  So better make the method return the result, it can also become more fluent this way:

```
Map<Object, Object> data = fillData(new HashMap<>());
```

What happens, if there is a value for "key" in the map before?  Will it be replaced or not?  The method can also be made free from side effects by returning a copy of the original map:

```
public static Map<Object, Object> filledData(Map<Object, Object> original) {
    Map<Object, Object> result = new HashMap<>(original);
    result.put("key","value");
    return result;
}
```

The functional approach is independent of the initial state:

```
Map<Object, Object> data = createFilledData();
```

What to use depends on the requirements, as always.  Is this a public API or an internal helper method?  Who will use it, novice or experts?  How about performance?